# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'new'

Tags: python, python-2.7, compiler-errors, traceback

I have some code that I would like to run. 
Im new to python, as well as stackoverflow

Here is the python program:

```
# Circle Inversion Fractals (Apollonian Gasket) (Escape-time Algorithm)
# FB36 - 20131031
import math
import random
from collections import deque
from PIL import Image
imgx = 512; imgy = 512
image = Image.new("RGB", (imgx, imgy))
pixels = image.load()
n = random.randint(3, 6) # of main circles
a = math.pi * 2.0 / n
r = math.sin(a) / math.sin((math.pi - a) / 2.0) / 2.0 # r of main circles
h = math.sqrt(1.0 - r * r)
xa = -h; xb = h; ya = -h; yb = h # viewing area
cx = [0.0]; cy = [0.0]; cr = [1.0 - r] # center circle
for i in range(n): # add main circles
    cx.append(math.cos(a * i))
    cy.append(math.sin(a * i))
    cr.append(r)
maxIt = 64 # of iterations
for ky in range(imgy):
    print str(100 * ky / (imgy - 1)).zfill(3) + "%"
    for kx in range(imgx):
        x = float(kx) / (imgx - 1) * (xb - xa) + xa
        y = float(ky) / (imgy - 1) * (yb - ya) + ya
        queue = deque([])
        queue.append((x, y, 0))
        while len(queue) > 0: # iterate points until none left
            (x, y, i) = queue.popleft()
            for k in range(n + 1):
                dx = x - cx[k]; dy = y - cy[k]
                d = math.hypot(dx, dy)
                if d <= cr[k]:
                    dx = dx / d; dy = dy / d
                    dnew = cr[k] ** 2.0 / d
                    xnew = dnew * dx + cx[k]
                    ynew = dnew * dy + cy[k]
                    if xnew >= xa and xnew <= xb and ynew >= ya and ynew <= yb:
                        if i + 1 == maxIt: break
                        queue.append((xnew, ynew, i + 1))
        pixels[kx, ky] = (i % 16 * 16 , i % 8 * 32, i % 4 * 64)
image.save("CircleInversionFractal_" + str(n) + ".png", "PNG")
```

When I run it, I get an error message but I don't know how to resolve it.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "U:\Personal\PythonFiles\Python Program Examples\Circle Inversion Fractals.py",   line 9, in <module>
 image = Image.new("RGB", (imgx, imgy))
 AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'new'
```

What does this traceback mean?

Comment: If you share the code you tried to use, it would help provide a more detailed answer.  Perhaps you are trying to use Ruby syntax in Python to instantiate an object?

Comment: Please do share your code so we can help you *correct* the error too. Are you trying to use the `hmac`, `sha`, `md5` or `hashlib` modules?

Answer (score 6):

It means that you are trying to use the name `new` on a module object:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.new
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'new'
```

It means the `sys` module has no attribute `new` here. It doesn't matter if you are treating `new` as a callable (function, method, class, etc.), in the expression `sys.new()` the name `new` will first be looked up as an attribute.

If you are trying to use a module that is documented to have a `.new()` method (such as [`sha.new()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sha.html#sha.new) or [`hashlib.new()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html), then make sure you don't have **another** module by the same name in your path. Don't name your own script `sha.py` when you try to import the standard library module `sha`!

You can check where a module was imported from by printing the `.__file__` filename:

```
 print sha.__file__
```

and if it is *not* a filename in your Python installation you perhaps need to investigate why you have an extra file in your path and rename that file or move it aside.

Comment: Awesome.. that line `Don't name your own script sha.py when you try to import the standard library module sha!` did the trick!

Comment: Thanks! I'd named my script hmac.py :-D